# How to transform C# byte[] to struct[]

Tags: c#, struct

In C# I have a struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Size = 3)]
public  struct int24
{
        private byte a;
        private byte b;
        private byte c;

        public int24(byte a, byte b, byte c)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public Int32 getInt32()
        {
            byte[] bytes = {this.a, this.b, this.c , 0};
            // if we want to put the struct into int32, need a method, not able to type cast directly
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        }

        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  content is ：  " + a.ToString() + b.ToString() + c.ToString());
        }
}
```

For `byte[]` to `struct[]` transformation, I use:

```
public static int24[] byteArrayToStructureArrayB(byte[] input) {
        int dataPairNr = input.Length / 3;
        int24[] structInput = new int24[dataPairNr];
        var reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(input));

        for (int i = 0; i < dataPairNr; i++) {
            structInput[i] = new int24(reader.ReadByte(), reader.ReadByte(), reader.ReadByte());
        }

        return structInput;
}
```

I feel really bad about the code.

Questions are:

1. What can I do to improve the function `byteArrayToStructureArrayB`?
2. As you can see in the int24 struct, I have a function called `getInt32()`. This function is only for bit shift operation of the struct. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public struct int24 {
   public int24(byte[] array, int index) {
      // TODO: choose what to do if out of bounds

      a = array[index];
      b = array[index + 1];
      c = array[index + 2];
   }

   ...
}

public static int24[] byteArrayToStructureArrayB(byte[] input) {
   var count = input.Length / 3;
   var result = new int24[count];

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      result[i] = new int24(input, i * 3);

   return result;
}
```